# Get value from list on onContextItemSelected ()?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi want to know can we get the value of a field defined in the list like id from database in
onContextItemSelected()? my code for creating context menu is pinning below, help appreciated, thnx

```
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    long clickedPosition = info.id;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case NEW_MENU_ITEM:
        //callActivity(1);
        break;
    case SAVE_MENU_ITEM:
        //callActivity(2);
        break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(0, NEW_MENU_ITEM, 0, "Delete");
    menu.add(0, SAVE_MENU_ITEM, 1, "Rename");
}
```

the following code not retiring my id from database

```
long clickedPosition = info.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    Object obj = getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position);
    String name = obj.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned in that field depends entirely on your adapter implementation.  It would be the same `id` that would be passed through to an `OnItemClickListener`, which is the value returned by `getItemId()` on your adapter.

If you are using `CursorAdapter` or a variant of that to supply the data to the list, then the `_id` column is the value returned by default, unless you have modified this method.  For an `ArrayAdapter`, this is not the case and you would have to add the code to return the ID you need.  If you need to pass back more complex data than just a single `int`, you could set a tag on the list item views with `setTag()` and retrieve it from the `ContextMenuInfo` since `targetView` is one of the parameters it carries.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the position of the element in this list by adding
 `int id= info.position` 
 in `onContextItemSelected`;

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> Set database_id as tag to your lisviewItem view.

```
    view.setTag(database_id );
```

And get database_id from onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) as

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        int listPosition = info.position;


        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case call:

            View view = info.targetView;
            String database_id=(String) view.getTag();
            return true;
        case defaullt: 
            return true;


        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```